# Matrix array overflow

Tags: matrices, matlab

I have an extremely large matrices and I can't show it in portrait or landscape size of a page. so is there any way to show the matrix with its array like command pretty do in Matlab.
[image: what Matlab pretty command do when the matrix arrays are overflow]

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 3):

I suggest you acquaint yourself with the `pmatrix` and `align*` environments. In the code below, I use `\xi` rather than `#` to denote the generic placeholder variable.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools} % provides '\shortintertext' macro, loads 'amsmath' package
\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
T_6 &= \begin{pmatrix}
    c_6 \xi_6+s_6\xi_3 & c_6 \xi_3-s_6\xi_6 &    
       s_5\xi_8+c_1c_5s_{23} & c_1\xi_1 \\
    -c_6\xi_5-s_6\xi_4 & s_6\xi_5-c_6\xi_4 & 
       c_5s_1s_{23}-s_5\xi_7 & s_1\xi_1 \\
    \dots & \dots & \dots & \dots \\
    \dots & \dots & \dots & \dots  
\end{pmatrix}
\shortintertext{where}
\xi_1 &= a_1+a_2c_2+a_3c_{23}+d_4s_{23}\\
\xi_2 &= c_{23}s_5+c_4c_5s_{23}\\
\xi_3 &= \dots
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```